# How can I intercept database requests(Peewee ORM) in pytest?

Tags: python, sql, mocking, pytest, peewee

I have a main database and a replica (they are the same in the test environment):

```
core_db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(**DB_COFIG)
replica_db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(**DB_REPLICA_COFIG)
```

A controllers that executes a query in different databases depending on the model

```
class BaseController:

    def _get_logs(self):
        query = self.model.select()
        if is_instance(self.model, ModelToReplica)
            query = query.bind(replica_db)
        return list(query)

class ReplicaExampleController(BaseLogsController):

    model = ModelToReplica

    def process(self):
        return self._get_logs()

class BaseExampleController(BaseLogsController):

    model = BaseModel

    def process(self):
        return self._get_logs()
```

Controllers are linked to two urls:

```
/get_core_result/ # Returns the result from BaseExampleController (core_db)
/get_replica_result/ # Returns the result from ReplicaExampleController (replica_db)
```

I want to check that each of the corners accesses the right base. And I know that the reference to the database object is stored in the request object. How do I get it from the test? I'm using a PyTest. I understand that I probably need to use mock, but I don't understand how.

Unfortunately, this is all I have so far:

```
class TestSwitchDB:

    def test_switch_db_to_replica():
        url_core = url_for('core_db_controller')
        core_result = self.client.get(url_core)

        url_replica = url_for('replica_db_controller')
        replica_result = self.client.get(url_replica)
```

Answer (score 1):

In *test_switch_db_to_replica* you can mock the db query and patch it, something

```
with patch(BaseController._get_logs) as mock_get_logs:
    mock_get_logs.return_value="your expected return"
```

As a reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html